# Hiding zero value in Word table after merge

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I have a Word Com Add-in that connects our online CRM (Maximizer) to merge fields in Word documents.  The `\# "$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)"` format switch works when I connect to field that is blank (does not contain any value), but when I connect to a formula field that contains a "0" (zero), the switch does not work to hide it.  I have tried to use dummy cells in the table to merge the values and then use a Word formula to insert them into the cell I want but still have the same problem.

This formula results in a syntax error if the value in B1 is 0:

```
{ =if(sum(Table2 B1:B1)=0,"", sum(Table2 B1:B1)) \# "$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)" }
```

This version with 0 instead of "" returns a visible $ 0.00:

```
{ =if(sum(Table2 B1:B1)=0,0, sum(Table2 B1:B1)) \# "$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)" }
```

[Code with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT8t7.png)

If I change the switch to ###.##, values like 325.00 will display as 325 so that is not an option.

The code for the merge field starts as:

```
{ DOCPROPERTY  UO.QuickbooksschrxfbkTotalsschrxfbkTotalschrx0020Lineschrx00201 \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

which I have tried changing to:

```
{ DOCPROPERTY  UO.QuickbooksschrxfbkTotalsschrxfbkTotalschrx0020Lineschrx00201 \# "##,##0.00;(##,##0.00)" }
```

But the result is the same.

I don't have an answer for this problem but while typing my question out, I thought of some other options and stopped to try them out.  I didn't solve it but I did arrive at a work around.

I applied the same solution I was trying to apply above, but instead of doing it in Word after the values arrive, I did it directly in my CRM. I created an alphanumeric formula UDF instead of a numeric formula UDF. I then wrapped the formula in a `text` function combined with an `if` statement as follows:

```
if(text(MyFormula)=="0","",text(MyFormula))
```

This is the only way I could have '0' values transfer to Word without as a blank value instead of a '0'.

If someone has a better answer, I would still be interested in knowing it.  If no one comes up with anything I will post my solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting point is that in most cases Word field numeric format switches/"pictures" can have up *three* parts.

If there's just one part, it's used to format every number

```
{ =x \#"'format for any number x'" }
```

If there are two parts, the first part is used for numbers that are positive or zero, and the second part is used for negative numbers

```
{ =x \#"'format when x >=0'" }
```

If there are three parts, the first part is used for positive numbers, the second part is used for negative numbers, and the third part is used for 0 numbers

```
{ =x \#"'format if x is positive';'format if x is negative';'format if x is 0'" }
```

My guess is that the program you are using only offers two possibilities, not three, and that in most cases, specifying the third part as '' will solve the problem where you want 0 to appear as blank.

Beyond that, the field

```
{ =if(sum(Table2 B1:B1)=0,"", sum(Table2 B1:B1)) \# "$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)" }
```

uses the IF function within a formula field { = }. AFAIK when Microsoft defined its .docx file formats it defined the { = } but forgot to describe the IF function. But as far as I know the IF function can only have *numeric* results, so this part won't work:

```
{ =if(sum(Table2 B1:B1)=0,""
```

If you cannot get your field coding to distinguish between an empty value and 0 using a `\#` switch, the remaining option is to use an { IF } field (not an { =IF() } field.

Something like

```
{ IF { myvalue } = "" "" "{ myvalue \#"whatever formats you need" }" }
```

The other important case when using numeric format switches in Word is "what if the thing being formatted is not a number?" And the simple answer to that is that in that case, Word does not apply any of the formats defined by the `\#`. Just bear in mind that there is a difference between

```
{ Bookmarkname \#0 }
```

And

```
{ =Bookmarkname \#0 }
```

In the second case, `=Bookmarkname` will always be a number, whatever the content of `Bookmarkname`. If `Bookmarkname` contains `abc`, Word does not find anything that looks like a number or numeric expression and sets the value of `=Bookmarkname` to 0.

Comment: Thanks johnson, using the third part worked.  I can't believe how much time I spent searching for an answer without success.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @DryBSMT glad that sorted it!